# What is the difference between Azure devops and VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Last year i am integrating VSTS with our testing environment but with new Azure devops it is completely change my old account of VSTS is working with my integration but new account of Azure devops (VSTS) is not working. Why it is happen.

Could not find any reference that's shows me breaking changes.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific problem you have encountered, you cannot login or some other problem?

Comment: There is no difference. Azure DevOps is a rebranding of the platform. Saying "it's not working" isn't enough information for anyone to be able to help you. Imagine someone is asking **you** for help with a problem they're having with software you're familiar with. Would you be able to help them if all they told you was "it's not working"? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron , Not Working means in VSTS there is Project Collection named Default Collection but in Azure there is no project collection, like this breaking change any more is there

Comment: @DanielMann , Not Working means in VSTS there is Project Collection named Default Collection but in Azure there is no project collection, like this breaking change any more is there

Comment: @NitinParashar You can only have a single team project collection in VSTS/Azure DevOps. That's always been the case. The only thing that's changed is that the URI is slightly different because it doesn't include the extraneous "DefaultCollection", since there will never be a case when there's anything *other* than "DefaultCollection". What specifically about that is "not working" for you? It is not a breaking change.

Comment: @DanielMann, yes if we make a generic environment that work with tfs server and vsts , in that we have to pass the collection name in rest api , if azure remove the default collection from their url for accessing the rest api, then it is a breaking change, does it is not.

Answer (score 2):

On September 10, 2018, Microsoft renamed Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to Azure DevOps Services.

VSTS features are now separate services:

[image]

For the url's change. We've moved to the new dev.azure.com domain name as the primary URL for new organizations. (Specifically, it's `https://dev.azure.com/{your organization}/{your project}`.)

If you want to change your URL to be based on dev.azure.com as the primary, an organization administrator can change this from the organization settings page.  We will also support redirects from visualstudio.com URLs so there will not be broken links.

For more information about this change, see [Introducing Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-devops/).

---

About the concept of collection in Azure DevOps, **Default collection is no longer present in the URL** for a long time. You could take a look at our PM's word:

> One important note – we have been working for some time to enable
>   grouping multiple VSTS organizations together under a higher-level
>   artifact. We had been calling this artifact an organization in blog
>   posts
>   (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/01/11/how-we-plan-to-enable-creating-multiple-collections-per-account/
>   and
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/04/09/merging-the-concepts-of-account-and-collection/)
>   as well as in our communication with some users already trying it out
>   in private preview. The work here will continue, and we’ll be coming
>   up with a new name for these groupings of organizations.

For the url of REST API, the request URI, in the following form:

```
VERB https://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

***instance:*** The Azure DevOps Services organization or TFS server you're sending the request to. They are structured as follows:

- Azure DevOps Services: `dev.azure.com/{organization}`
- TFS: `{server:port}/tfs/{collection}` (the default port is 8080, and
  the value for collection should be DefaultCollection but can be any
  collection)

We do not use collection concept in Rest API of Azure DevOps, so you do not need to specify it in the url. Actually Azure DevOps organization is collection level, TFS is server level, they are not the same level, one TFS server could have multiple collections.